# facing problem using DatePicker in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

I am using DatePicker from package:date_picker_timeline

here I want to set start date:-30 days of current date and
end date: +30 days of current date

and It should be shown current date when I start app..I mean showing today date and I can be able to move and forward upto 30 days

I am failing to finding regarding properties, and it should be shown current date with selected when app starts...

```
DateTime.now(),
                initialSelectedDate:DateTime.now(),
                selectionColor: Colors.blue,
                monthTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                onDateChange: (DateTime date) {
                  setState(() {
                    selecteddate = date;
                    //print("Selected Date is :"+selecteddate.toString());
                  });
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take help from `activeDates` parameter,

```dart
DatePicker(
  DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 30)),
  activeDates: List.generate(
      60,
      (index) => (DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 30)))
          .add(Duration(days: index))),
  initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
  selectionColor: Colors.black,
  selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
  onDateChange: (date) {},
),
```

Comment: but its not showing previous 30 dates....

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. updated

Comment: here I want to implement one more thing, but recently u said that it need scroll otherwise not possible

Comment: here while giving activate dates -30 to +30 , its working but to move to current date I have to scroll upto that today date.. is there any option that shows current date on start and we can have choice to move +30 and -30

Comment: You can add a controller and animate to the index after first frame is build. the package last update was 16th months ago, need some support I think

Comment: is there any such package where I can get same design I like the way it designs

Comment: It might be a little complicated but you can try with indexToScroll package, or while the width will be fixed, listView with controller may work better